# How to Pause Firebase Message Delivery(Cloud Messaging)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Was trying to test Firebase Cloud Messaging via "Compose notification" feature, Was trying to test but by mistake it delivery to all real users, is there any way to PAUSE this delivery? and is there any report\stats where can see actually who received that test Push? FYI after few mins i realized then i DELETED that test message but not sure how many users received that.

Comment: You can't pause FCM's message delivery. Depending on the specs of the message, every user within it would've received it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Yes i realized that, and current UI looks like it allow you to test your firebase from create message screen, and if you proceed to do tthat hen you will be in trouble(test message will be deliver to all), except if you think i missed way to fire test message to selected device?